# How can I let my custom user control accept a list of properties in ASP.NET WebForms?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

Let's say I have a user control that contains a file upload field and a submit button:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ImageUploader.ascx.cs" Inherits="MyProject.ImageUploader" %>

<asp:FileUpload ID="fileInput" runat="server"/>
<asp:Button ID="submitButton" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="UploadImage" />
```

I would like to pass in multiple sizes to resize an uploaded image to. I know how to do this from code behind, but I would like to be able to use my user control like this:

```
<%@ Register tagPrefix="uc" tagName="ImageUploader" src="ImageUploader.ascx" %>

<uc:ImageUploader id="uploader" runat="server">
    <Sizes>
        <Size Width="640" Height="480" />
        <Size Width="320" Height="240" />
    </Sizes>
</uc:ImageUploader>
```

How can achieve I something like this? I have no idea how this concept is called so that makes searching for it a bit difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your user control(ImageUploader) you sholud create property like this one

```
 public List<Size> Sizes { get; set; }
```

Of course, you must create class Size

```
 public class Size
 {
    public int Width { get; set; } 
    public int Height { get; set; } 
 }
```

After that, you can use this property somethimg like this

```
<uc:ImageUploader id="uploader" runat="server">
    <Sizes>
        <asp:Size Width="120" Height="340"/>
        <asp:Size Width="170" Height="540"/>
        <asp:Size Width="130" Height="740"/>
    </Sizes>
</uc:ImageUploader>
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. I was trying it without `asp:` and that didn't work. When I added the `asp:` ReSharper asked me if I wanted it to add `<%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="Full.Namespace.Of.SizeClass" Assembly="MyProjectAssembly" %>` and that fixed it. I didn't know I had to register the namespace of the Size class. Thanks for the help!